# Youtube Data Api V3, is scraping the JSON sites legal? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am having some confusion implementing the YouTube Data Api v3. I tried looking up tutorials and copy pasting the sample code to learn from it (after setting everything up of course) but I run into an error where:

import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth; doesnt exist and hence the whole sample doesn't work. I haven't found a fix online. I hate just copying code and putting on Android and making it run without understanding what it does. I couldn't find a solution to this problem!

What was my solution?
I scraped (using Java) links such as:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatistics%2CcontentDetails%2CtopicDetails&forUsername=&key=

where all I have to do is input my browser key and the youtuber's username in order to retrieve the data that I needed. I am wondering if this is legal to do? These are their JSON sites that the API itself uses. The reason I am worried is because I recently got into scraping and read a lot about it's legal issues.

Thank you!

PS: I am using my browser key, and if I plan to release an app which utilizes this method is it a problem since the key will be used by multiple people?

Answer (score 0):

First, You have to open SDK Manager. Install Google Play Services if you haven't.

Then, You open the build.gradle and add the library to it. (Replace ? with the correct version)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:?.?.?'
```

After syncing your gradle, then you should be able to import the library.

**Edit:**

If you find https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3 is useful, then you can use it because it belongs to the [official API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/).

Comment: I definitely have play services working and the youtube player api working. The player and adMob is setup and running.

Comment: @DanielS Would you like to share part of your code and state what is not working? Your question is not very clear to me. Also, please read my edit.

Comment: As of now I got rid of all the code with the setup sample and I need to set it up again. For now I want to know if my technique is allowed under googles policies or not

Comment: Yes, as long as you follows their Terms of Use. There is qouta usage that you should read. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota